# Create Plist from content of URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, plist

I've made a PHP file which prints out all the source code for a working plist and I can successfully retrieve data from a database into my app this way.

However I don't want the app to always go online to get the database, so I want the user to be able to specify when he/she wants to update the plist (by pressing a button "update database").

My code to get the plist:

```
NSURL *url_ = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost/~user/plist.php"];
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url_];
```

This works great, however the user shouldn't have to be online to use the database...

What I want to do is to replace this with a local plist, which is simple.

And whenever the button is clicked "update database" I want to download the new plist from the url and replace the one locally saved.

Hope you understand what I mean :)

Thanks in advance
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do to save your file is use the method `writeToFile:atomically` that returns a BOOL to tell you if the file was saved.

Here goes a code example:

```
NSArray* a = [NSArray new]; 
BOOL sucess = [a writeToFile:@"my.plist" atomically:YES];
if (!sucess) {
    NSLog(@"Ups, not saved");
}
```

After that you can load your file from yours documents path

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1  Create a list of paths.
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.plist"]; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
    NSarray* a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
   }
}
```

It probably will solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Do this write your plist data to document directory like this:

```
  [arrImages writeToFile:@"yourDocDirPathWithPlist" atomically:YES];
```

Now plist created and stored in document directory